# How to show HUD with custom UIView using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiview, uikit, hud

I have looked into HUDContentType and still here is no the case to supports SwiftUI implementation.

How to show SwiftUI View inside PKHUD/HUD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created HUD extension which implements show function with **SwiftUI** parameter.

```
extension HUD {
    public static func show<Content: View>(content: Content, frame: CGRect = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)) {
        let view = UIView(frame: frame)
        let hostView = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        hostView.view.frame = frame
        view.addSubview(hostView.view)
        let constraints = [
            hostView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            hostView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            hostView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            hostView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

            hostView.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            hostView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
        ]
        view.addConstraints(constraints)
        HUD.show(.customView(view: view))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let alert = Text("SwiftUI Alert Text")
HUD.show(content: alert)
```